# How to send log messages to server from angularjs application using log4javascript framework?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the below code in angular js to prepare a logger for sending messages to server.

```
var demo = angular.module('ng-logging', []);

demo.config(function ($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('$log', function ($delegate, $sniffer) {

        var _info = $delegate.info; //Saving the original behavior
        var _error = $delegate.error; //Saving the original behavior
        var log = log4javascript.getLogger();
        var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender('/api/log');

        ajaxAppender.setThreshold(log4javascript.Level.ALL);

        log.addAppender(ajaxAppender);

        $delegate.info = function (msg) {
            _info(msg);
            log.info(msg);
        };

        $delegate.error = function (msg) {
            _error(msg);
            log.error(msg);
        };

        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Server side:

```
public class PaymentController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/log")]
    public void Log(string message)
    {

    }
}
```

Usage: I am trying to use the $log provider configured above to send a message to server as below.

```
var payControllers = angular.module('pay.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap']);

payControllers.controller('PaymentCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'payDataService',
  function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, service, $log) {

$scope.sendPayment = function () { 
    $log.info("Sending payment");
    };
 }]);
```

When I test this, I get an error saying '$log is undefined'. I am not sure what is the correct way to implement this. I am trying to follow this article.
http://statelessprime.blogspot.com/2013/10/send-logging-and-exceptions-to-server.html

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplished the same thing client side. I overwrote the default $log angular logger by defining a factory method on my main module. (angular already has a logger defined at $log) . This may be why you get a $log is undefined. I also noticed that you did not set a layout for your appender. I reccomend using a json layout. Otherwise you only get an http post and you have to parse the string yourself. I can't help you server side because I have no idea what web framework you're using. Lastly,don't forget to inject the "$log" into your factory/directive whatever.

```
angular.module('main_module')
.factory('$log', function() {
    var logger = log4javascript.getLogger();

    var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender("/restfulConfigApi/logger.api");
    ajaxAppender.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ajaxAppender.setWaitForResponse(true);
    ajaxAppender.setLayout(new log4javascript.JsonLayout());

    //ajaxAppender.setRequestSuccessCallback(requestCallback);
    logger.addAppender(ajaxAppender);
    return logger;
});
```

Example of injecting the $log

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
angular.module("main_module").directive('a directive', a_directive);
conContextualIntelligencePublisher.$inject = [ "blah"... , "$log"];

function a_directive(blah ... , $log) { ... }
```